# WP+jquery read more, smoother slidedown/replace?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm setting up a Wordpress site with short news excerpts in a sidebar, with a jQuery read more button showing the rest of the post straight away without linking to another page.
The goal is to get a smoother read more-slide down than I currently have.
The main problem I have is that splitting the posting into two sections, from a WP perspective, with one excerpt field and one with a (rest of the) content field, will not be user-friendly enough. Therefor I am using the follow code at the moment:

```
            $(function () {
             $('.content').hide();
             $('a.read').click(function () {
                 $(this).parent('.excerpt').hide('fast');
                 $(this).closest('.article-jquery').find('.content').slideDown('fast');
                 return false;
             });
             $('a.read-less').click(function () {
                 $(this).parent('.content').slideUp('fast');
                 $(this).closest('.article-jquery').find('.excerpt').slideDown('fast');
                 return false;
             });
         });
```

and:

```
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="article-jquery">   

    <h2 class="front-small-header" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

        <div class="excerpt">
        <?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 15 ); ?><a href="" class="read">Read More</a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
        <?php the_content(); ?><a href="" class="read-less">Read Less</a>
        </div>

</article>
```

You can clearly see the first block of the excerpt disapearing and the new partially repeated part sliding over it.
Is there a way to make all of this a bit smoother/not looking weird?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [hide "complete" argument](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) to ensure one animation completes before starting the next. That may tidy things up a bit.

```
$('a.read').click(function () {
    $(this).parent('.excerpt').hide('fast', function() {
        $(this).closest('.article-jquery').find('.content').slideDown('fast');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Ended up using a plugin called collapse-o-matic which was a bit smoother.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand this solution, but here is how I would solve it myself.

1. Remove the element ".excerpt".
2. Set the lineheight on content to something nice, say 2.2 for example. Then the max-height of ".content" to 8.8 with an overflow:hidden. This will give us 4 rows of text.
3. When click on read-more, we remove the max-height.

   CSS

   ```
   .content {
       line-height: 2.2em;
       max-height: 8.8em;
       overflow: hidden;
   }
   ```

   jQuery

   ```
   // Let's trigger all elements that has a class that starts with "read-"
   $('[class^="read-"]').on('click',function(){
       // Since .content is .read-more's parent, lets take the parent()
       // And use slideToggle instead of checking if element is open or closed
       $(this).parent().slideToggle();
   });
   ```

   Markup

   ```
   <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="article-jquery">   

       <h2 class="front-small-header" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

       <div class="content">
           <?php the_content(); ?><span class="read-more">Read More</span>
       </div>

   </article>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Ended up using a plugin called collapse-o-matic which was a bit smoother.